# LINQ compare values for the same year , different month and doing a count if value has changed

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I have a data set that looks like below:

```xml
Option | Year | Month | Value 
-------+------+-------+------
   1   | 2011 |   12  |   0
-------+------+-------+------
   1   | 2011 |   11  |   1
-------+------+-------+------
   2   | 2012 |    6  |   0
-------+------+-------+------
   2   | 2012 |    7  |   0
-------+------+-------+------
   1   | 2011 |    6  |   2
```

The result set I am looking for is below :

```xml
Option | Year | ChangedCount
-------+------+-------------
   1   | 2011 |      3
-------+------+-------------
   2   | 2012 |      0
-------+------+-------------
```

Changed Count represents , if the value has changed in the same year between different months . so say if the value of 06 month was 2 and then 07 it changed to 1 , then changed count will be 1 . If the value for two months remains the same , then changedCount is 0

Here is what I have written so far

```
var changes = from ord in resultSet
    group ord by new
    {
        ord.Year,
        ord.Month,
        ord.Option,
        ord.Value,
    }
    into g
    select new
    {        
        Year = g.Key.Year,
        changed = g.Count(x => x.Value == 0) 
            + g.Count(x => x.Value == 1) 
            + g.Count(x => x.Value == 2)     
    };
```

How do I run comparison for previous value in column ?

{0,1,2} Map ENUM values

Comment: Can you clarify what type of aggregate function you're expecting `ChangedCount` to represent? Is it the sum of value within all grouped `Option` records? Is it the absolute change from the previous `Value` within an `Option`? Is it a count of all `Value` records with a value above `1`? I'm not entirely clear. The `g.Count()` logic in your current code doesn't seem to be evaluating the previous value, and effectively seems to be the same as `g.Count(x => x)`, assuming your range of values is limited to `{ 0, 1, 2 }`.

Comment: Changed Count represents , if the value has changed in the same year between different months . so say if the value of 06 month was 2 and then 07 it changed to 1 , then changed count will be 1 .

Comment: You have only `0` and `1` in `Value` column, but use `x => x.Value == 2` in `Count()`. Could you please explain, what is logic for `ChangedCount`?

Comment: @user1110790: That makes sense; thank you for clarifying. Will you always only have two months per year, or do you potentially need to account for multiple months in a year? If so, how do you intend to handle that logic? E.g., is it the difference between the lowest and highest value? Or the sum of the differences between each adjacent records?

Comment: if Jan - 1, Feb - 0, Mar - 2, Apr - 2, May - 0 is changedCount = 4?

Comment: @Matt.G The changedCount will be 5 for that specific year . If all months in the year had the same value, that option need not be counted .

Comment: For @Matt.G example, it changed `1` from jan to feb, then `2` from feb to mar, `0` from mar to apr, and then `2` from apr to may, for a total of `5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I understand from your explanation:

```
class Record
        {
            public int Option { get; set; }
            public int Year { get; set; }
            public int Month { get; set; }
            public int Value { get; set; }
        }


var resultSet = new List<Record> {
                new Record { Option=1, Year=2011, Month=12, Value=0   },
                new Record { Option=1, Year=2011, Month=11, Value=1  },
                new Record { Option=2, Year=2012, Month=6, Value=0   },
                new Record { Option=2, Year=2012, Month=7, Value=0   },
                new Record { Option=1, Year=2011, Month=6, Value=2   },
            };
```

Helper Method to count changes:

```
    public static int changeCount(List<Record> Records)
    {
        int previous = Records[0].Value;
        var result_change = 0;
        //i used sorted records by month you can do not this if order is not sensitive
        foreach (var rec in Records.OrderBy(x=>x.Month))
        {
            if (rec.Value != previous)
            {
                result_change++;
            }
            previous = rec.Value;
        }
        return result_change;
    }
```

and the actual code :

```
      var changes = resultSet.GroupBy(x => new { x.Year }).Select(g => new
        {
            Year = g.Key.Year,
            changed =changeCount( g.ToList()),
            Option = g.First().Option
        }).ToList();
```

Result :

```
 2011,3,1
 2012,0,2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var changes = from ord in resultSet
                       group ord by new
                       {
                          ord.Option,
                          ord.Year,
                       }
                       into g
                       select new
                       {
                          Option = g.Key.Option,
                          Year = g.Key.Year,
                          ChangedCount = g.Select(x => x.Value).Sum()
                       };
```

OR

```
resultSet
  .GroupBy(x => new { x.Option, x.Year })
  .Select(x => new { x.Key.Option, x.Key.Year, ChangedCount = x.Select(x => x.Value).Sum() });
```

Comment: @MattG the 0,1,2 map to ENUM values hence I cannot apply SUM

Comment: cast the enum to int like: `x => (int)x.Value`

Comment: I am getting multiple rows for 2011 , I only need one which has the changed count for the year .

Comment: what should be the value of Option in the result, when there is Option 1 and Option 2 for 2011? are we going by the min value of Options for the year?

Comment: I see the issue with my data , fixed it , for each year find out how many times an option has changed .